# Xamarin PCL profile 111 GetMethod only available in debug

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, portable-class-library

I have run into an issue where I would like to use GetMethod but the method does not exist according to intellisense when composing code. In favor of GetMethod there is GetRuntimeMethod which when used, the project builds. 
However when I try get a method it always returns null.

code in question is looking at SQLiteAsyncConnection and trying to get "CreateTableAsync"

```
Type dbConnection = Database.GetType();
MethodInfo method = dbConnection.GetRuntimeMethod("CreateTableAsync", new Type[]{});
```

This returns null... BUT, if I put in a breakpoint and write

```
dbConnection.GetMethod("CreateTableAsync");
```

in my Immediate window... the method exists and returns the proper MethodInfo.

Why?

Comment: Thanks, I actually found my problem though. It was that CreateTableAsync has one parameter but a default value CreateFlags = CreateFlag.None so I assumed I did not need anything in my Type array. Adding "new type[]{typeof(CreateFlags)}" returned the MethodInfo.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using reflection to get and invoke your method, the linker will not see it directly invoked. Hence when building your app in Release mode the Linker will strip the code out.

To prevent this you need to hint the Linker that it should not remove this code.

One way of doing this is to create a class which never is invoked at runtime, but is enough to hin the linker:

```
[Preserve(AllMembers = true)]
public class LinkerPleaseInclude
{
    public void Include(SQLiteAsyncConnection connection)
    {
        connection.CreateTableAsync();
    }
}
```